# Can I use a "last update" timestamp to select MySQL records for update?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database with about 30,000 rows.  I update this database to a remote server nightly, but never are more than 50 rows updated at a time.  I am the only one who updates the database.  I would like to develop a method in which only CHANGED rows are exported to the remote server.

To save space in the database and to save time when I export to the remote server, I have built "archive" tables (on the remote server) with records that will no longer be updated, and which do not reside on the local database.  But I know splitting up this data into multiple tables is bad design that could lead to problems if the structure of the tables ever needs to be changed.

So I would like to rebuild the database so that ALL the records with similar table structures are in a single table (like they were when the database was much smaller).  The size of the resulting table (with all archived records) would exceed 80,000 rows, much to large to export in a whole-database package.

To do this, I would like to
(1) Update a "last updated" timestamp in each row when the row is added or modified
(2) Select only rows in tables for export when their "last update" timestamp is greater than the timestamp of the last export operation
(3) Write a query that builds the export .sql file with only new and updated rows
(4) Update the timestamp for the export operation to be used for comparison during the next export

Has anyone ever done this?  If so, I would be grateful for some guidance on how to accomplish this.

Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a column with a `timestamp` datatype, for example `last_updated timestamp`, it will be automatically updated to `now()` every time a row changes.

Then early every day, simply ship yesterday's changes:

```
select * from mytable
where last_updated between subdate(CURDATE(), 1) and CURDATE()
```

Comment: Nice solution; also need to declare the `last_updated_timestamp` column as `NOT NULL` I think.

Comment: I liked a derivation of this suggestion!  While I was testing with an automatically updating timestamp, at one point every timestamp column in the table was changed (and I couldn't determine why).

Since I write my own entry screens, I have complete control over what's in each record.  The original timestamp was set when each record was created.  I added code to replace that with a current timestamp when records are added or changed (should have done this at first anyway), rather than rely on an ONUPDATE replacement.

Comment: Then I added a new table into which is stored the timestamp of the creation time of the current update.sql file.  The script checks for records with a later timestamp than the stored on, and writes an "update.sql" file containing the REPLACE INTO... statements for my update.  Then it writes the current timestamp into the new table for the next update.

So far testing is going well.  Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: P.S.  As a result my update .sql files run under 50KB rather than the 2.3MB files created by phpMyAdmin...

Answer (score 0):

Why not just setup the remote server as a replication slave?  MySQL will only send updated rows in that situation, and very quickly / efficiently at that.

Using an official replication strategy is generally advisable rather than rolling your own.  You'll have lots of examples to work from and lots of people who understand what's going on if you run into problems.

Comment: This looks like a great suggestion, but the learning curve is daunting.  Since I write my own entry screens, I have complete control over what's in each record.  See my other reply to see what I'm doing.

Comment: I would argue that you're making your life more difficult by rolling your own.  MySQL replication is a matter of running a few commands - that's it.  Of course you need to understand them, and there is a learning curve there, but it's really not too hard.  Also in a year or so from now, if something breaks, you'll have a much easier time figuring out the problem when you can reread the MySQL docs rather than trying to understand your own code.  Who do you trust more to get replication right - yourself or the MySQL developers?  :)